# Toast works fine in main Activity but not in a class

Tags: java, android, toast

Using `Toast` in the `MainActivity` works fine

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Button is clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

but when I use it in a class, `getApplicationContext()`, gets red lined and it does not work. How can I make it work in a class?

Comment: yes you can make and if getapplication not work then put context

Comment: Could you post the error it show?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to pass the context from Activity to the non Activity class and use the same there

```
  new NonActivityClass(ActivityName.this);
```

Then

```
 COntext mContext;
 public NonActivityClass(Context context)
 {
     mContext =context;
 }
```

Then

```
 Toast.makeText(mContext, "Button is clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Note : Do not keep long-lived references to a context-activity (a reference to an activity should have the same life cycle as the activity itself) to avoid memory leaks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get toast from class , you should send context to your class.